# Increased size of react-app after deployment

Tags: css, node.js, reactjs, firebase, npm

This is my second app-clone using react. After deployment the apps size is increased. It is normal in my localhost3000, but it increases when I deploy it. Please need help.

[This is my localhost3000 app view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IV5DE.jpg)

[This is my deployed app-version view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1Unn.png)

Comment: Make sure the Zoom level is normal (100%). Press `Ctrl + 0` to do that.

Comment: You can also click on the magnifying glass to the far right of the url, then click `reset`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are in minimized view in development version.
[image]